# Chrome extension to sync files with USB drive

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible for a chrome extension to sync files and directories between a USB drive and the main HDD?
This might be useful for example for easy downloading of photos from a digital camera.

To implement this feature, one will need two main parts:

1. read-write access to the local hard drive
2. read-write access to the USB drive

#1 is covered by the HTML5 filesystem APIs (see [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/) for example).

#2 is the problematic part, as I don't know of any available mechanism that allows that.
It might be possible to somehow utilize the [USB experimental api](http://developer.chrome.com/trunk/apps/experimental.usb.html) to implement a mass-storage device protocol.
However, my knowledge in USB protocols is too limited to know whether this is actually possible or what it may involve.

Thanks

Comment: I was under the assumption that the file APIs were for Chrome **OS** only?

Comment: Actually it is going to be part of the HTML5 specs, see here: http://dev.w3.org/2009/dap/file-system/pub/FileSystem/

Comment: The ChromeOS file API is an API that let you access the file manager on ChromeOS. I guess here @Giladd is talking about HTML5 USB API and the way to work with files on top on it, right?

Comment: I edited the question to make it more clear where the problem is.

Comment: Chrome API already cover [USB](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/usb) and [FileStstem](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem), that's what you need?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution (though it's a Big Hammer) is to use a [Native Host](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#native-messaging) - basically, a separate program that has full OS APIs, and to which your extension talks.

Cons include the fact that the native host cannot be bundled with the extension in the Web Store, unlike NPAPI plugins (which are no longer an option).

`chrome.usb` and `chrome.fileSystem` APIs mentioned in another answer are not available for Chrome extensions, only apps.